# Trying to store grep result into array but want each value to be stored as a different key

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

Hi I am new to scripting and am trying to get my hear around arrays.

I have created a text file called colours which contains the following data:

```
1=red
2=black
3=blue
```

I want to store each colour into a array as a separate key,  but the code I use below stores result as a single key.  I think I need to grep line by line in the loop but not sure

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a result1
for result in $(grep 1= colours |cut -d "=" -f 2)
do
    result1+=("$result")
done
echo ${result1[@]}
```

Comment: What do you think `grep 1=` does and why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Transform your file with `sed -E 's/(.*)=(.*)/result1[\1]="\2"/' file` to this:

```
result1[1]="red"
result1[2]="black"
result1[3]="blue"
```

and get it with `source` in your current environment:

```
source <(sed -E 's/(.*)=(.*)/result1[\1]="\2"/' file)
```

See output of `declare -p result1`:

```
declare -a result1=([1]="red" [2]="black" [3]="blue")
```